# Partial nested struct does not get inherited

Tags: c#

```
public class Base<T>
{
    T _data;

    public partial struct Data
    {
        public T _data;
    }
}

public class Custom : Base<int>
{
    public partial struct Data
    {
        public float _bla;
        public bool _bla2;
    }

    public void BlaBla()
    {
        Data data = new Data();

        //int data = data._data; <= NOT FOUND
        float bla = data._bla;
        bool bla2 = data._bla2;
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the Data class is defined twice in the parent class and the child class.

In addition, Custom defines additional member variables as needed.

However, Data._data inside the Base is not accessible.

...
Why is this happening?

Comment: There's no concept of "inheriting" nested classes. If you want `Custom.Data` to be in any way related to `Base<T>.Data`, you'd need to explicitly inherit from it (after switching from `struct` to `class`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the Data class is defined twice in the parent class and the child class

Exactly. You have two different types whose names end in `Data`, but they have no relation whatsoever.

From the C# specification:

> Each part of a partial type declaration must include a partial modifier. It must have the same name and be declared **in the same namespace or type declaration** as the other parts.

Because they're nested in different types, they're different types themselves. The `partial` modifier does nothing in this regard; they're partial types consisting of exactly one part.

Answer (score 4):

Partial classes is just syntax sugar in msil there are no partial classes. In this case you create 2 different classes. You don't have type `Data`, you have types `Custom.Data`and `Base<T>.Data`.

```
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Custom.Data));
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Base<string>.Data));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See the other answers from @CodeCaster and @Max Mokrousov as to why.

Here's a way to have the result you want by inheriting from the base Data class:

```
public class Base<T>
{
    T _data;

    public class Data // Note that it's a class now instead of a struct
    {
        public T _data;
    }
}

public class Custom : Base<int>
{
    public class DataCustom : Base<int>.Data
    {
        public float _bla;
        public bool _bla2;
    }

    public void BlaBla()
    {
        DataCustom data = new DataCustom();

        int dataBase = data._data; // now works
        float bla = data._bla;
        bool bla2 = data._bla2;
    }
}
```